# How to get lat/lon of a mouse click with Bing Maps AJAX Control v7

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

I am using th newest version of the API (v7), and would like to add a pushpin on mouse-click ...

```
var mapSettings = {
    'credentials': 'myCredentials',
    'mapTypeId': Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.road,
    'enableSearchLogo': false,
    'showMapTypeSelector': false,
    'showScalebar': false
};

var $map = $('#map');
var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map($map.get(0), mapSettings);
Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(map, 'click', function (e) {
    var latitude = ?
    var longitude = ?
    var location = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(latitude, longitude);
    var pushpin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(location, {
        'draggable': true
    });
    map.entites.push(pushpin);
});
```

As you see, I am stuck within the click-handler: How do I get latitude & longitude of the click?

Comment: for those wondering, in Bing Maps v8 , the location is hanging right off of the callback param ( e ).      `e.location
n {latitude: 39.29711299974974, longitude: -111.57935390625, altitude: 0, altitudeReference: -1}`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ok, nailed it. Here's the bit of code that you're interested in:

```
if (e.targetType == "map") {
  var point = new Microsoft.Maps.Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
  var loc = e.target.tryPixelToLocation(point);
  var location = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(loc.latitude, loc.longitude);
  ......
}
```

`e.target.getLocation()` only works when the target is a pushpin, infobox, etc. The click on the actual map is different.

Comment: nope ... sry `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getLocation' of undefined`

Comment: I updated answer to use `e.target` instead of `e.entity`. See if that works. I can't test this right now.

Comment: nope ... sry ... `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<tr> has no method 'getLocation'`

Comment: I seem to get this to work on the map itself, contrary to your statement. Clicking on one of my pushpins results in an error, though (Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tryPixelToLocation'). I haven't tested it on infobox because I don't know what that is.

Comment: `e.target.tryPixelToLocation(point)` returns a Microsoft.Maps.Location object, so there's no need to grab the lat and lon from that to create a new one.